# Is there any way to list down datetime range between 2 datatime in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have 2 set of datetime data in different column and i would like to list down, the range within the 2 date and time of a same row.

example, i tried below the output does not shows the range of datetime

```
import pandas as pd

a = '2020-11-17 13:35:18'   
b = '2020-11-17 13:36:09'

tt= pd.date_range(start=a,end=b)
print(tt)

OUTPUT:
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 13:35:18'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

expected output would be:

```
['2020-11-17 13:35:18','2020-11-17 13:35:19',,'2020-11-17 13:35:20','2020-11-17 13:35:21','2020-11-17 13:35:22','2020-11-17 13:35:23','2020-11-17 13:35:24','2020-11-17 13:35:25',
'2020-11-17 13:35:26','2020-11-17 13:35:27','2020-11-17 13:35:28','2020-11-17 13:35:29','2020-11-17 13:35:30','2020-11-17 13:35:31','2020-11-17 13:35:32','2020-11-17 13:35:33',
'2020-11-17 13:35:34','2020-11-17 13:35:35','2020-11-17 13:35:36','2020-11-17 13:35:37','2020-11-17 13:35:38','2020-11-17 13:35:39','2020-11-17 13:35:40','2020-11-17 13:35:41',
'2020-11-17 13:35:42','2020-11-17 13:35:43','2020-11-17 13:35:44','2020-11-17 13:35:45','2020-11-17 13:35:46','2020-11-17 13:35:47','2020-11-17 13:35:48','2020-11-17 13:35:49',
'2020-11-17 13:35:50','2020-11-17 13:35:51','2020-11-17 13:35:52','2020-11-17 13:35:53','2020-11-17 13:35:54','2020-11-17 13:35:55','2020-11-17 13:35:56','2020-11-17 13:35:57',
'2020-11-17 13:35:58','2020-11-17 13:35:59','2020-11-17 13:36:00','2020-11-17 13:36:01','2020-11-17 13:36:02','2020-11-17 13:36:03','2020-11-17 13:36:04','2020-11-17 13:36:05',
'2020-11-17 13:36:06','2020-11-17 13:36:07','2020-11-17 13:36:08','2020-11-17 13:36:09']
```

Comment: pd.date_range(start=a,end=b, freq='S')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason of your  output is if not set `freq` parameter is used default.

So set `S` for seconds frequency:

```
tt = pd.date_range(start=a,end=b, freq='S')
print(tt)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11-17 13:35:19',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:20', '2020-11-17 13:35:21',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:22', '2020-11-17 13:35:23',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:24', '2020-11-17 13:35:25',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:26', '2020-11-17 13:35:27',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:28', '2020-11-17 13:35:29',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:30', '2020-11-17 13:35:31',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:32', '2020-11-17 13:35:33',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:34', '2020-11-17 13:35:35',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:36', '2020-11-17 13:35:37',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:38', '2020-11-17 13:35:39',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:40', '2020-11-17 13:35:41',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:42', '2020-11-17 13:35:43',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:44', '2020-11-17 13:35:45',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:46', '2020-11-17 13:35:47',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:48', '2020-11-17 13:35:49',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:50', '2020-11-17 13:35:51',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:52', '2020-11-17 13:35:53',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:54', '2020-11-17 13:35:55',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:56', '2020-11-17 13:35:57',
               '2020-11-17 13:35:58', '2020-11-17 13:35:59',
               '2020-11-17 13:36:00', '2020-11-17 13:36:01',
               '2020-11-17 13:36:02', '2020-11-17 13:36:03',
               '2020-11-17 13:36:04', '2020-11-17 13:36:05',
               '2020-11-17 13:36:06', '2020-11-17 13:36:07',
               '2020-11-17 13:36:08', '2020-11-17 13:36:09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='S')
```

Comment: can i know why if put in datateframe format it cannot convert input?

`df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['2020-11-17 13:35:18'],
                   'date2': ['2020-11-17 13:36:50']})
df = pd.date_range(start=df['date1'],end=df['date2'], freq='S')
print(df)

TypeError: Cannot convert input [0    2020-11-17 13:35:18
Name: date1, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp`

Comment: @BBBBBBBB - You need seelct one eleemtn Series to scalar like `df = pd.date_range(start=df['date1'].iat[0],end=df['date2'].iat[0], freq='S')`